# install4j: Read XML from HTTP Request

Tags: install4j

I need to read a xml string from a HTTP request before. I already safe the complete xml string to an installer variable, but it seems that I can only use the "Read value from XML file" with files, and not with variables.

Is there a way?

Greetings, 
Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to save the installer variable to a temporary file first.

Add a "Write text to a file" action after the "HTTP request" action and set its "Text" property to `${installer:variableName}` where `variableName` is the name of the variable that contains the XML document. The "File" property can be set to `${installer:sys.workingDir}/request.xml`.

The working directory is a temporary directory, so that file will be deleted when the installer exits.

In your "Read value from XML file" action you can then set the "XML file" property to `${installer:sys.workingDir}/request.xml`.